# Best way to communicate in multiprocessing between processes.

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to write a function that will be run as a separate process and will be acquiring data until I tell it to stop on the main process.

Here is how it works:

```
e = multiprocessing.Event()

def recordLeverPos(e, name): #e = multiprocessing.Event()
    posData = []
    while True:
        datBuffer = str(lever.readCounter()) + '\n'
        posData.append(datBuffer)
        if e.is_set() == True:
            with open('%s_leverPos.tsv' %(name), 'a') as file:
                for i in range(len(posData)):
                    posData[i] = posData[i]
                    file.write(posData[i])
            print 'Done Writing to leverPos file.'
            while e.is_set() == True:
                sleep(0.01)
            posData = []


p = mp.Process(target=recordLeverPos, args = (e, name))

def trialStart():
    global e

    #While trials is going on, some more code regarding the correct task that must be performed.
    e.set() #Indicate to the process that it's time to flush the buffer to the tsv file.


    #Depending on conditions, trial may continue to trial stop a function in which the patient must not do anything to the lever, but I still need to record the lever position.
    e.clear() #Indicate to process to get out of the while loop and start recording a new leverPos buffer.
    trialStop()

def trialStop():
    global e
    #Patient must not do anything here.... but if he/she does.
    if (lever.readCounter > threshold): #Patient  moved it.
        e.set() #Indicate to thread it's time to flush the buffer again.
        e.clear() #Indicate to thread you can start with a new buffer.

        #However the problem seems to be that when I call the e.set() in this function the process does not receive the event and does not save the Buffer... 

    #there's a timer here, if the timer passes I still want to record the position of the lever.

def main():
    p.start() #Begin adding leverPos to the buffer.
    trialStart()
```

So I call that function and make it into a process that runs separately from my main function.

```
p = mp.Process(target=recordLeverPos, args = (e, name))
p.start()
```

The function **recordLeverPos** basically records positions of a lever by adding it to a list buffer, when the trial is over I call `e.set()` and thus the next part of the function is called which is basically copying the list buffer onto a a `tsv` file. Then the process will wait until I call `e.clear()`. 
Here's the problem: I can't seem to have consistent clearing of the event (it's worth noting that I made p and e global variables such that they can be accessed from other functions that run certain stages of the trials). Whenever I call `e.set()` it only seems to work for two of the four different places I call `e.set()`. 
My question is, why is this happening? Is there a better way to be able to do this in a way that I can call it globally?

Is there a better way to communicate with processes? 
I tried searching myself, but I couldn't figure out how to use pickable objects, and to be honest, the event function/class seemed more intuitive to me, but I can't seem to be able to use it like I'd expect it to work...

Let me know if you would like a bit more code, I just tried to super simplify my code such that you get the main idea and thus you don't waste time trying to understand how my code works.

Comment: You can use sockets (https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html). However, I can't seem to figure out the solution to your first problem about the set() function.

Comment: It's very strange, I discovered that if I make the script sleep for a few ms before it calls e.clear() the separate process receives the message and proceeds to store the buffer to the file.
Hmm I'm not sure if sockets is the best solution since these functions run from the same script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some sample code that allows data to trickle in, then when an event is signalled, the data is written to a file.  It's freestanding and has no dependencies.

Point to note:

- after the `Event` is checked with `is_set()`, it's immediately cleared. This lets the parent process `set()` it again

That's pretty much it, the original code was nearly complete!

### source

```
import multiprocessing, sys, time

record_ev = multiprocessing.Event()
name = 'beer'

def recordLeverPos(rec_ev, name): #e = multiprocessing.Event()
    posData = []
    lever = iter(xrange(999))
    while True:
        datBuffer = str(lever.next()) + '\n'
        posData.append(datBuffer)
        print 'posData',posData
        if rec_ev.is_set():
            rec_ev.clear()
            with open('%s_leverPos.tsv' % name, 'a') as dataf:
                for dat in posData:
                    dataf.write(dat)
            print 'wrote: {}'.format(posData)
            print 'Done Writing to leverPos file.'
            posData = []
        time.sleep(1)


record_proc = multiprocessing.Process(
    target=recordLeverPos, args = (record_ev, name)
)
record_proc.start()

time.sleep(2)
print 'triggering record'
record_ev.set()

time.sleep(2)
print 'triggering record #2'
record_ev.set()

time.sleep(2)
record_proc.terminate()
record_proc.join()
sys.exit(0)
```

### output

```
posData ['0\n']
posData ['0\n', '1\n']
triggering record
posData ['0\n', '1\n', '2\n']
wrote: ['0\n', '1\n', '2\n']
Done Writing to leverPos file.
posData ['3\n']
triggering record #2
posData ['3\n', '4\n']
wrote: ['3\n', '4\n']
Done Writing to leverPos file.
posData ['5\n']
```